# Copy B1 to B10, C1 to C20 into A11 to A20, A21 to A30,...... in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy data from rows B1 to B10, C1 to C20 into A11 to A20, A21 to A30,...... in Excel for multiple columns. All Data from all column A to Column NF in my case should be under Column A. I tried using Transpose but failed.

I have added a image if that helps.

Please let me know if any better way to proceed. Thanks

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHr5n.png)

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed3VI.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try using for A11:... a formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MOD(ROW()-1;10)+1;(ROW()-1)/10+1))
```

Comment: I didn't notice. Well, B1:B10 and C1:C20 won't fit into A11:A30 anyway.